# In a post intergalactic WW3 where most of scociety has moved into a VR world to escape, what created the zombies that roam outside (Not nuclear war)

Tags: post-apocalypse, zombies, dystopia, virtual-reality

Basically, this is after a war between human civilizations on multiple planets in our galaxy. Most people have decided to live the rest of their lives in a fully immersive VR world and a very small number have stayed behind to maintain the VR systems.

There are zombies outside the secure VR facilities which would want to attack and kill any human that stepped foot outside.

I know the obvious answer is nuclear war, but radiation does not create zombies and I am looking for something more plausible.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting to start a discussion or get help with idea generation/brainstorming. Such questions aren't the best fit for this site. What are the specific issues you are having with determining the origins of your zombies? You'll get much more focused and useful answers if you [edit] your post to ask that question.

Comment: Nobody knows and nobody cares except the maintenance crew whom spend their off-time pointing fingers at one another. Some say it was the Riders. Others say it was the Diggers. I think it was Mark because he doesn't cover his mouth when he coughs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for ideas for major plot points, not to solve a problem in developing plot.

Answer (score 5):

The prototype VR environment had side effects. Nanites or viral DNA to adjust humans to the subversive VR environment didn't work exactly as they had hoped.

Comment: I was on my way to post this.

Answer (score 5):

/what created the zombies?/

**Propaganda.**

There are parties interested in maintaining the status quo.  It serves these parties to let their customers know that the world outside the VR dens is full of zombies and other dangers.

[image: children]

In actuality, there are people out there.  Some might eat you if they were that hungry.  Some act crazy and run around.  Mostly though, they are just people, trying to get by, the way people do.

Comment: This is a very nice, almost poetic, answer. Hats off!

Answer (score 4):

## Biological Weapons

Nuclear war *wouldn't* create zombies, except in science fantasy, as you say, so "obvious choice" is a bit unlikely.  Additionally, I don't think "WWIII" is apropos if the conflict spans multiple worlds.

A virus or other biological agent that makes a human incredibly, indiscriminately violent towards other humans, turns off their pain sensation so they can't easily be stopped, and causes them to be unable to do anything useful for society seems like a great thing to drop behind enemy lines, if one is unconcerned about war crimes.

It also seems like the kind of thing that could accidentally spread to one's own population.

And hey-presto, the 30% of humanity that is susceptible to this virus become zombies.  A clever genetic engineer on the side that released the virus (and both sides claim the other did it) also made it able to reside without symptoms in various animal reservoirs, so the risk remains indefinitely.

Comment: You can always combine the two ideas of course. The Fallout universe's mutations are explained that way (without it being intended as a biological weapon). The [Forced Evolutionary Virus](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Forced_Evolutionary_Virus) was supposed to improve lifeforms (improving intelligence, boosting strength, enlarging smaller lifeforms, etc.), but when a nuclear weapon hit the facility manufacturing it, a mutated form spread across the wasteland, one which did those things *wrong*.

Answer (score 4):

**A human-pathogenic fungus**

On Earth [entomopathogenic fungi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomopathogenic_fungus) are known. They exploit insects for their own life cycle. See for instance [Ophiocordyceps unilateralis](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/cordyceps-zombie-fungus-takes-over-ants).

In your case it would be a more evolved life form preying on mammals and especially mammals with large brains.
Humans would be the most common such life form the fungus could find for mankind has spread all through the galaxy and can be found in large numbers.
Also the war (people really would just simply call it like that) disrupted health care systems and prevention agencies making the spread and adaptation of the fungus easier.
It is up to you to decide how the fungi spread on to a new individual. The classic bite may be the way to carry the spores as they may not be suited to be airborne.
Furthermore you could make in your story that such fungus was in fact a man made evolution horror made during the war. But that is a bit cliché.

How about the fungus being a sentient being keen on evolving both its own species AND the humans into new, more enlighted beings, who would avoid the madness that war is?
But this is plot and up to you. Here we just do the world building :)

Consider anyway:

- the fungus has a vested interest in keeping the host alive for the necessary amount of time
- the fungus wants to spread itself / its species
- the fungus is capable of directing the actions of the controlled host and use its receptors to a certain extent
- the fungus can release drugs to inhibit or enhance behaviors of the host (suppressing fear, pain, compassion and increasing aggressiveness and alienation)
- the fungus may have some collective communication capability but at a slower rate compared to humans. Hence the directing of hordes of zombies may be slower

For all this reasons an alien fungus may be a pretty good explanation for zombies in space.

P.S. Ed Wood would have **loved** this!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us#Plot